# Non-equi join for a group of variables without providing intervals

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data sets from two different providers, recording grades of students under different ids. A few students appear in both data sets.

```
DT1 = data.table(id   = 1:6,
                 math = c(6.55, 7.39, 5.89, 9.70, 4.77, 5.30),
                 engl = c(8.55, 8.83, 9.20, 9.10, 4.32, 8.17),
                 hist = c(7.37, 3.39, 8.11, 2.10, 1.58, 6.65),
                 geog = c(10.0, 7.63, 2.37, 8.44, 6.35, 7.10))

DT2 = data.table(id   = LETTERS[1:6],
                 math2 = c(6.55, 7.39, 5.88, 9.70, 4.17, 9.70),
                 engl2 = c(8.53, 6.83, 9.19, 9.10, 4.22, 9.10),
                 hist2 = c(7.39, 2.39, 8.12, 2.10, 1.58, 2.10),
                 geog2 = c(10.0, 7.43, 2.38, 8.44, 6.45, 8.44))
```

I want to merge both of them, in order to know the ids correspondence. To do that I have to match on the grades. Problem is that the different data sets have different rounding, so, to find students on both data sets, I have to match on the closest grades.

As of now I am doing the following

```
subj = names(DT2)[-1] # get the subjects

#create interval on the grades, so I can run the non-equi join
DT2[, paste0(subj, "_min") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x - 0.02), .SDcols = subj]
DT2[, paste0(subj, "_max") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x + 0.02), .SDcols = subj]

DTm = DT1[DT2, on = .(math >= math2_min, math <= math2_max,
                      engl >= engl2_min, engl <= engl2_max), nomatch = 0]
```

In summary, I create intervals of grade +/- 0.02 and do a non-equi join, which results in the right answer (in the example above I have a duplicate in DT2, which is fine).

However, I would like to do it without providing an interval, because I don't know which interval to provide.

Is there a way to do a non-equi join that matches on the closest value? When I say closest I mean, find the closest value for `math` in `math2` and then the closest value for `engl` in `engl2`. If both values are from the same observation, then its a match, if not, then there is no match.

Comment: Unfortunately I think there is no easy "non-equi join" function. However, can you round them off to the nearest 0.02 or 0.04? (E.g., `trunc(x*50)/50` for 0.02) and then join on equality? This may produce more matches, but if you join on multiple columns you'll have a lower likelihood of an incorrect match.

Comment: What does "closest value" mean in the context of your multi-dimensional match?

Comment: @eddi I am editing to be more precise

Comment: @r2evans I didn't want to do it by rounding because and don't actually know why some grades are different. I do know that all students in DT1 have to be in DT2, but I am not that comfortable giving myself the "error rule"

Comment: Then if eddi's answer doesn't meet your needs, you'll likely need to use a "distance" function (perhaps just `dist`) from all students of `DT1` with all students of `DT2`; though it doesn't scale well, my guess is that you aren't doing it for millions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to satisfy your definition of closest, but does not match your example results:

```
DT1[DT2, on = .(math = math2), roll = 'nearest', math.id := i.id][
    DT2, on = .(engl = engl2), roll = 'nearest', engl.id := i.id][
    math.id == engl.id]
#   id math engl hist  geog math.id engl.id
#1:  1 6.55 8.55 7.37 10.00       A       A
#2:  3 5.89 9.20 8.11  2.37       C       C
#3:  4 9.70 9.10 2.10  8.44       F       F
#4:  5 4.77 4.32 1.58  6.35       E       E
```

Comment: My example result was the right answer given the interval I provided, but it was not the answer I was looking for. Your method is. Thanks